# Twitter API on JS Web View - Create a Twitter Clients that tweets on behalf of users

Tags: javascript, twitter, webview, oauth-1.0a, twitter-client

I need to make a very simple Twitter Client in JavaScript (Web View - not Node) like https://hootsuite.com/dashboard#/publisher, that will send users to authenticate on twitter and then, be able to fetch their tweets (and the tweets of the people they follow) and enable them to tweet a simple message.

I created a Twitter app (without a website config because I need it for Web View), and I'm having serious issues while trying to implement all the oAuth 1.0 procedure, and also the other parts (maybe because I don't understand how to use the oAuth).

So, my questions are:

1. is there any library that can help me to achieve this?
2. Is there any way I can implement this by myself easily?
3. Is there any option, thanks to Web View, to make this flow simpler by maybe using some native code? (Need it for both Android & IOS)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm soon writing a blog post about this.

Comment: I'm not using any library so far, but you can do it even without any libraries. But you can create your own library though for your specific application needs